# Powershell script with "az webapp create-remote-connection" pauses at this instruction

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm attempting to script a backup process of a docker volume hosted in a azure linux app service.
I need to create a ssh tunnel using powershell. Calling the script from task scheduler with the following `powershell -noninteractive -File R:\path\to\ftp-backups.ps1`

When the following command is executed to create the tunnel

`az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription 00000000-9dfs-4fdsxexxxx-324jklsdf4308320324 --resource-group my-resource-group -n my-app-name -p 12345`

The powershell dialog that has come up offers the interactive options of

```
Opening tunnel on port: 12345
SSH is available { username: user, password: password }
Ctrl + C to close
```

The script does not move past this point, how can I suppress this interactive dialog prompt so the rest of the script will continue?

Answer (score 0):

I responded to your question on a different [forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/54823/index.html). Posting here for visibility

The engineering team revamped this command recently which was deployed as part of CLI release 2.8.0. The PowerShell script should work now.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/blob/master/docs-ref-conceptual/release-notes-azure-cli.md#appservice-1